# Shell script execution is failed with error " No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, rhel

I Have written a shell script which simply show the swap memory usages from processes.
I have executed the script at my end successfully, but when I share this with client to execute it is getting failed at their end with below error.

`$dzdo ./MemoryUsage.sh`

`dzdo: unable to execute ./MemoryUsage.sh : No such file or directory`

What is the use of dzdo, because I have't used that command while executing script?

**Below is the script file content:**

```
#!/bin/bash
overall=0
for status_file in /proc/[0-9]*/status; do
    swap_mem=$(grep VmSwap "$status_file" | awk '{ print $2 }')
    if [ "$swap_mem" ] && [ "$swap_mem" -gt 0 ]; then
        pid=$(grep Tgid "$status_file" | awk '{ print $2 }')
        name=$(grep Name "$status_file" | awk '{ print $2 }')
        printf "%s\t%20s\t%8s KB\n" "$pid" "$name" "$swap_mem"
    fi
    overall=$((overall+swap_mem))
done
printf "Total Swapped Memory: %18u KB\n" $overall
```

Comment: what is "pwd" or "ls" outputs. Is there MemoryUsage.sh file?

Comment: `dzdo` seems to be some kind of `sudo` alternative: https://docs.centrify.com/Content/aud-events/dzdo.htm